# How to handle query parameters on routes that require login in shopware 6?

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have a controller that redirects requests to other domains. The routing looks like this:

```
/my-controller/link-on-another-server?with=parameters
```

The routes require a login. Here is the catch: the query parameters get lost when the user is not logged in and gets redirected to the login page. The target page does not work properly without the parameters.

How can I fix that?

I was considering another route, which would be called from frontend, that stores the query parameters in the session and redirects to a route which requires the login and then loads the parameters out of the session.

Is there another way to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this Issue by using custom fields. I have one or two links per product or per category. I retrieve the product or category in the controller and I load the destination url from the product/category custom fields.